# Upgrading Kubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 - it want to install Ubuntu 12.04 instead

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, release-upgrade

I'm unable to upgrade using the instructions here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades/Kubuntu

I've installed all updates, but I cannot see any new version available.
I had to change muon-updater to see normal dist upgrades even though 12.04 should be a LTS. After changing this, I'm able upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, not Kubuntu.
I'm afraid to just press install... Running the following command (found on the earlier linked page) also want's to upgrade to Ubuntu rather than Kubuntu..

```
do-release-upgrade -m desktop -f kde -d
```

Any idea what might be wrong? Or should I just go for Ubuntu and hope for the best?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Go ahead.

Kubuntu is just Ubuntu with some other packages installed. Do the upgrade. If when it finishes you get into the Unity interface(Ubuntu) at logon, then click the gear icon and select KDE, although this shouldn't happen. If there isn't even an option for KDE Plasma workspace, then simply install `kubuntu-desktop` using Synaptic or `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: So nothing bad will happen? The pictures in the link I gave showed "Kubuntu" everywhere, while it says "Ubuntu" here.

Comment: @simendsjo Nothing bad will happen that cannot be fixed. Simply, all packages, including Kubuntu packages, are upgraded.